Rails 7 - Adding textAttributes to trix affects the paste functionality
I'm trying to add a highlight button to Trix editor and it works ... but on paste text, it also applies the highlight. Looks like the tagNamespan It's used for all the pasted text and also affects the functionality. I tried to capture the paste event and handle it but that duplicates the paste.
 // actiontext.js
import Trix from "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"


Trix.config.textAttributes.backgroundYellow = {
  tagName: "span",
  inheritable: true,
  parser: (element) => element.style.backgroundColor === "yellow",
  style: { backgroundColor: "yellow" }
}


class BackgroundYellow {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element
    this.editor = element.editor
    this.toolbar = element.toolbarElement

    this.injectHTML()
    this.installEventHandlers()
  }

  injectHTML() {
    const backgroundButtonHTML = `
      <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-higlight" data-trix-attribute="backgroundYellow" title="Background Yellow" tabindex="-1" style="bottom: 5px; background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000%22%20stroke-width%3D%222%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%20stroke-linejoin%3D%22round%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M6%2019h12v-2H6v2z%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M6%2020v3h12v-3M9%2015h6v2H9v-2zm2-2h2v2h-2v-2z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');">Y</button>
    `;
    this.toolbar.querySelector(".trix-button-group--text-tools").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", backgroundButtonHTML);
  }
  

  installEventHandlers() {
    this.toolbar.querySelector("[data-trix-attribute=backgroundYellow]").addEventListener("click", this.toggleBackground.bind(this))
  }

  toggleBackground() {
    this.editor.recordUndoEntry("Toggle background color yellow")
    const range = this.editor.getSelectedRange()
    const selectedText = this.editor.getSelectedDocument().toString()

    if (selectedText.length > 0) {
      const element = document.createElement("div")
      element.setAttribute("class", "backgroundYellow")
      // element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
      element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedText))

      this.editor.setSelectedRange(range)
      this.editor.insertHTML(element.outerHTML)
    }
  }
}


document.addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
  new BackgroundYellow(event.target)
})

Ideas on how to just highlight the text when you select and apply the format and do not affect the pasted one ?
